# Java Virtual Machines (JVM) and their performance comparison

Tags: oracle, jvm, sun, java

I was wondering if there somebody knows if there are some benchmarks which compare the following jvms.

sun jvm vs. openjdk jvm vs. rockit jvm vs. j9 jvm vs. apache harmony.

Which one is has the best performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer really depends on a number of your application characteristics. See here for an example: http://jmob.ow2.org/jvm.html

To get an idea of some common criteria, try Googling: jvm performance benchmark

Comment: The benches listed at that link are many, many years out of date and no longer provide any sort of meaningful answer.  I would not recommend them.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I don't think most off-the-shelf benchmarks are useful unless you know why. My answer was just that I find old benchmarks helpful in understanding these why's.

Answer (score 5):

[This one is pretty recent.](http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=9)

NOTE: Of course benchmarks are just that, a limited set of canned routines. They really do not give you a real view of the picture

Comment: This one is ok - it's a pity that jrockit is not included in the benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very hard, considering each JVM has different strengths and weaknesses.

I would look to the SPEC benchmarks - [SPECjbb2005](http://www.spec.org/jbb2005/) & [SPECjEnterprise2010](http://www.spec.org/jEnterprise2010/) - they are current, peer reviewed and actively run by many companies (unlike the jmob.ow2.org benches, which were vaguely current in the Pentium 3 era!).